# Rest API Issue after Upgrading JDK and Spring

Tags: java, spring, performance

Im having an api slowness issue after upgrading my application from Java 7 to Java 8 and SPring 3 to Spring 4

I was tasked to upgrade our application simple API that have JDK 7 and Spring 3 , to JDK 8 and Spring 4 , performance before was 300 ms and now its 1100 ms

I tried using Jmeter for testing and running it on local and remote machine its still the same result

Any suggestions how can I improve or determine the culprit of my issue?

New Performance with JDK8 and Spring 4

[image: New Performance with JDK8 and Spring 4]

OLd Performance with JDK7 and Spring 3
[image: OLd Performance with JDK7 and Spring 3]

New Performance with JDK8 and Spring 4 Summary
[image: New Performance with JDK8 and Spring 4 Summary]

OLd Performance with JDK8 and Spring 4 Summary
[image: OLd Performance with JDK8 and Spring 4 Summary]

Comment: You should input any benchmark and relevant code here. Try to guess the reason without architecture, source code, benchmark is nearly impossible

Comment: Thanks Manh I updated my post with the result of the performance in jmeter